# Navigation Controller to Pushviewcontroller to New View Controller with WebKit Delay/Slow on First Load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pushviewcontroller

The setup is simple.   I have a NavigationController that is loading just fine.  When I click on a table row or button to load the new controller that is loading with WebKit, there is 2-3 second delay, the very FIRST time I load it.   After it loads once, all is well.  I can go back and the transition is instant.

There is no shortage of this question in Stackoverflow, but every single one of these has the same accepted answer for Swift 5.  This hasn't helped me.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let newController = MyWebViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
    }
```

Again, it's only occurring the very first time.

Here is my code in the new VC too.

```
private lazy var webView = WKWebView()

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by loading a UIView first via ViewDidLoad and then loading webkit via viewdidappear.